# Problem While pushing into Scratch Org

Tags: lightning, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin

When I trying to push into my Scratch Org from CLI, using the command `sfdx force:source:push -u TestScratchOrg -f`
then I'm encountering the error

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of null
    at C:\Users\703224811\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.57.1-dbf54fc584\node_modules\jsforce\lib\api\metadata.js:53:16
    at tryCallOne (C:\Users\703224811\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.57.1-dbf54fc584\node_modules\promise\lib\core.js:37:12)
    at C:\Users\703224811\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.57.1-dbf54fc584\node_modules\promise\lib\core.js:123:15
    at flush (C:\Users\703224811\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.57.1-dbf54fc584\node_modules\asap\raw.js:50:29)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

I'm using the VSCode for this purpose and I'm using the CLI version `7.57.1-dbf54fc584` Which I guess the most recent version.

Comment: I guess you are trying to push some NodeJS related code as well? Looks like it could be related some compilation error with the source code.

Comment: Maybe you don't have node.js installed on your computer, try again after installing it. Salesforce cli requires node.

Comment: @Raul node.js is already installed in my system and currently, I'm running on  v12.13.0 version of node.js

Comment: Could you then try updating npm and sfdx then try again?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. It has been intermittent but is now very consistent. I have the latest node and sfdx updates installed. Help?!

Comment: Try to run command "sfdx update" and then use push command.

Comment: Thanks @AbhishekGangwar but I have updated both sfdx-cli and salesforcedx via npm to [at]latest and had no luck. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling via both the windows installer as well as using npm. I did find a hacky solution which I'll post on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a somewhat hacky solution for this problem.
The problem exists at ...AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.57.1-dbf54fc584\node_modules\jsforce\lib\api\metadata.js:53:16
(in my file, it's actually at line 54 but I'm also on version 7.85.0 rather than 7.57.1).

The line there is `return res.result;`
The author has not checked for a null result.

If you change this line to `return res !== null ? res.result : {};` the code will not fail.

Now, I'm uncertain of why res is coming back as null and I haven't found any problems so far since I altered it but use at your own risk. I'm not sure if this was just an oversight or if res being null indicates a component was not pushed correctly. Again, I have not found any problems with pushing since I changed this and there are no components that are missing or anything - but I haven't dug through the code enough to find out why res is null and what that means.

Hope this helps someone out there. It drove me nuts for months!

Thanks,
Duncan